# Rest Api $_GET not working

Tags: php, html, json, rest

I am new in JSON and as I progress I have this problem where I cant have my $_GET function to work. I created a JSON api using PHP from my mysqli database here is how

```
<?php
function get_data()
{
$connect = mysqli_connect("***", "***", "***", "***");
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$users = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $users[] = array(
        'userID'        =>  $row['userID'],
        'userName' =>  $row['userFirstname']." ". $row['userLastname']
    );
}
$users_array = array('users' => $users);

return json_encode($users_array);
}

$file_name = "asd.json";

    if(file_put_contents($file_name, get_data())) {
    echo $file_name . 'is creeated!';
}
```

And it created successfully and here is how I use that JSON and I am using get and I can't get it to work with $_GET calls

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_GET['userID'])){
$url = "http://batz.web/Sandbox/asd.json?userID=" . 
urlencode($_GET['userID']);

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($json, true);


}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sand.css">


    <title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="">
    <input type="text" name="userID">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </br>
    <?php
        if (!empty($array)){
            foreach($array['users'] as $id){
                echo '<a href="#">
                        <div class="choices">
                            <dl>
                                <dt>'.$id['userID'] .'</dt>
                                <dd>'.$id['userName'].'</dd>    
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                      </a>';
            }
        }
    ?>
    </form>
```

The main problem is whenever `index.php` is opened it wont print any. But when i submit something that is equals to `userID` everything is just showing.

Thank you in advance for advice and fix to come. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are putting all users in json file, so passing userID by query string to this file is unnecessary.

Change it:

```
if (isset($_GET['userID'])){
$url = "http://batz.web/Sandbox/asd.json?userID=" . 
urlencode($_GET['userID']);

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
}
```

to it:

```
$url = "http://batz.web/Sandbox/asd.json";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Change it:

```
$users[] = array(
    'userID'   =>  $row['userID'],
    'userName' =>  $row['userFirstname']." ". $row['userLastname']
);
```

to it:

```
$users[ $row['userID'] ] = array(
    'userName' =>  $row['userFirstname']." ". $row['userLastname']
);
```

If you want to get an unique user, so "foreach" is unnecessary too.

Change it to:

```
<?php
    $id = isset($_GET['userID']) ? $_GET['userID'] : NULL;
    if (!empty($array['users'][$id])){
                 echo '<a href="#">
                    <div class="choices">
                        <dl>
                            <dt>'.$id.'</dt>
                            <dd>'.$array['users'][$i]['userName'].'</dd>    
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                  </a>';
```

Comment: Thanks sir! This have worked! Could've think of this earlier! Still thank you so much!